# Hiding the connection string to the database in app.config C# forms

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, app-config

After creating a program in the output files contain app.config with connection settings to the database. How can I hide from the user's eye this line? And best of this file at all. 
Program C # wpf

Thank you!

Comment: there are built in ways to do this.. http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-webconfig/ or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20398/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-ConnectionString-in-app-config

Answer (score 0):

Change settings visibility to Internal in your project properties